# My network setup do not work. FreeBSD

Tags: dhcp, nat, freebsd, hostapd, pf

This question was asked by me on `serverfault.com`. It was closed as off-topic, with a suggestion to ask here, on `superuser`. The OS is `FreeBSD 13.0`.

The setup that I need to establish is simple. In human terms, in simple words, I can describe the setup is below.

1. My laptop is connected to ISP through Ethernet cable.
2. I want it(my lap) to transmit WiFi signal, to act as a WiFi router to other devices. So my laptop will be an AP, or a router, you name it.

The result that i want is that my guests, and me, can use the internet through my laptop.

I had followed some forums and FreeBSD handbook, but my cell-phone still refuses to go online. Though I can ping it from my laptop.

My idea was to use `dhcpd` on a `wlan0` network interface. After that, I was taught to not to reinvent a bicycle, but use a `NAT`. In FreeBSD `pf` terms it will be something like(taken from the forums): `nat on re0 inet from  ! (re0) to any -> (re0)`. So I want everything from `!re0`, `re0` being my cable to ISP, to be translated to `re0`. My humble thinking is that, that some device connects to AP, gets an IP of a `wlan0` subnet, and
traffic gets routed through a `NAT` to the `re0` cable connection.

Now the cell-phone gets an IP. I can ping the cell-phone. But no internet on a cell-phone.

I will update the information about my actual setup per request.

Please, if anyone has some working config, or step-by-step guide, as of how to make a simple thing come to life... **How to make my laptop to act as a typical WiFi router?**

**UPDATE**

This is my pf config. As I mentioned earlier, I have `DHCP` service that works on `wlan0`. The external interface, `re0`, configured with static address.

```
# The name of our network interface as seen in `ifconfig`
ext_if="re0"
usb_if="ue0"
wlan_if="wlan0"

all_ifs = "{" $ext_if $usb_if $wlan_if "}"

# Macros to define the set of TCP and UDP ports to open.
# Add additional ports or ranges separated by commas.
# UDP 60000-60010 is mosh control http://mosh.mit.edu/
tcp_services = "{ssh, http, https}"
udp_services = "{60000:60010}"

# If you block all ICMP requests you will break things like path MTU
# discovery. These macros define allowed ICMP types. The additional
# ICMPv6 types are for neighbor discovery (RFC 4861)
icmp_types = "{echoreq, unreach}"
icmp6_types="{echoreq, unreach, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137}"

# Modulate the initial sequence number of TCP packets.
# Broken operating systems sometimes don't randomize this number,
# making it guessable.
tcp_state="flags S/SA keep state"
udp_state="keep state"

# send RST
set block-policy return

# Exempt the loopback interface to prevent services utilizing the
# local loop from being blocked accidentally.
set skip on lo0

# all incoming traffic on external interface is normalized and fragmented
# packets are reassembled.
scrub in on $all_ifs all fragment reassemble

# set a default deny policy.
block in log all

# This is a desktop so be permissive in allowing outgoing connections.
pass out quick modulate state

# Enable antispoofing on the external interface
antispoof for $all_ifs

# block packets that fail a reverse path check. we look up the routing
# table, check to make sure that the outbound is the same as the source
# it came in on. if not, it is probably source address spoofed.
block in from urpf-failed to any

# drop broadcast requests quietly.
block in quick on $all_ifs from any to 255.255.255.255

# Allow the services defined in the macros at the top of the file
pass in on $all_ifs inet proto tcp from any to any port $tcp_services $tcp_state
pass in on $all_ifs inet6 proto tcp from any to any port $tcp_services $tcp_state

pass in on $all_ifs inet proto udp from any to any port $udp_services $udp_state
pass in on $all_ifs inet6 proto udp from any to any port $udp_services $udp_state

# Allow ICMP
pass inet proto icmp all icmp-type $icmp_types keep state
pass inet6 proto icmp6 all icmp6-type $icmp6_types keep state

# forward packets from wlan0 to re0(cable)
nat on $ext_if inet from ! ($ext_if) to any -> ($ext_if)
```

To be honest, I copy-pasted the above from some FreeBSD forum. With the above setup, I can ping my cell-phone, but that's all.

**UPDATE**

I've tidied `pf.conf` to

```
...
nat on $ext_if from $int_network to any -> $ext_if
pass out all
pass in all
...
```

Nevertheless, `tcpdump` on `pflog0` interface shows no activity at all. I do not know a simple way to test network packet traffic that goes from `$int_if`. The internal network gets addresses assigned, but the packets that should go to `default` gateway are missed somewhere.

**Update**

`tcpdump` on "internal network" interface showed that the gateway for this interface, `192.168.0.1`, is asking for the route to the default gateway. The default gateway is on different network, and no routes were added to the routing table. So the cell-phone just keeps broadcasting for the `default`(cable) gateway.

I made changes to `dhcpd.conf` with a `DNS`'es being of `ISP`'s network, gateway(router) is `192.168.0.1` and the rest is as usual for the file.

The command `route add -net <ISP gateway> <192.168.0.1>` made a difference.

***Mark as semi-closed, for myself***

**Update**

Because the nature of my LAN, WI-FI dongle can be plugged out at any time,
I had to add some scripts with `devd.conf` to dynamically add/delete route from internal network
default gateway to the ISP default gateway.

Simply put two scripts(`rtwn0_up.sh` and `rtwn0_down.sh`) into `/usr/local/sbin/`.
The possible action for notify(calling those scripts), when the network interface is UP/DOWN is :

```
# rtwn0.conf
# /etc/usr/local/devd/

 1 notify 100 {                                                                                                          
 2     match       "system"     "IFNET"
 3     match       "subsystem"  "rtwn0" # name of the interface for my WI-FI dongle
 4     match       "type"       "LINK_UP"
 5     media-type  "802.11"
 6     action      "/usr/local/sbin/rtwn0_up.sh"
 7 };
 8
 9 notify 100 {
10     match       "system"     "IFNET"
11     match       "subsystem"  "rtwn0" # name of the interface for my WI-FI dongle
12     match       "type"       "LINK_DOWN"
13     media-type  "802.11"
14     action      "/usr/local/sbin/rtwn0_down.sh"
15 };
```

I searched through SO web, and can not find a similar problem.
Just had to admit, that reading `FreeBSD` documentation about useful services,
could had saved me a lot of time. I just start to getting myself familiarized
with `devd`. But even at this point, I feel that it is a great way to gather all
scripting burden in one place.

Comment: Do you have `gateway_enable="YES"`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I do. I think I just have to read carefully `man pf`. I copied blindly a set of `pf` rules. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you, but the post is lengthy and its setup is somewhat different from what I have.

Answer (score 0):

The NAT part of the setup boils down to

**/etc/rc.conf:**

```
ifconfig_re0="..."
ifconfig_wlan0="..."


gateway_enable="YES"
pf_enable="YES"
```

**/etc/pf.conf:**

```
ext_if="re0"
int_if="wlan0"

nat on $ext_if from $int_if:network to any -> ($ext_if)
pass from { lo0, $int_if:network } to any keep state
```

You'll have to add DHCP on top of that.

Comment: I think I have a somewhat similar setup. Care to look at? Also, my `sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding is {0}`. I read somewhere that this is no longer relevant with more recent setup. Still, documentation from 199x mention it as a first step. Do I need to turn it on?

Comment: @user14063792468 Setting `gateway_enable="YES"` should turn it on.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you. For now, I have no access to my setup. As soon as I do, I will update on the question and accept answer per result.

Comment: @arrowd with the above config added to `pf.conf`, still no internet with a cell-phone.

Comment: The `$int_if:network` causes an error at `pf` startup. It is a WI-FI network and the interface could be up/down at any time.